# Не удаётся из url получить фото

Tags: python, requests, pillow, google-colaboratory

не удается из ссылки получить фотографию, она почему-то не преобразовывается и постоянно выдает ошибку. Из-за этого не получается распознать текст с фотографии, которую подаю, уже не знаю, что делать, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
import os 
import io 
import requests 
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError 
import pytesseract 
import telebot 
import csv 
import re 
import time 
from PIL import ImageFile 
     photo_url = message.photo[-1].file_id 
     photo_info = bot.get_file(photo_url) 
     time.sleep(1) 
photo_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{6084234069}/{photo_info.file_path}'   
    try: 
        # Скачиваем фотографию 
       ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True 
       response = requests.get(photo_url) 
       a = io.BytesIO(response.content) 
       img = Image.open(a) 
    except (UnidentifiedImageError, OSError) as e: 
        print(f"Ошибка загрузки изображения: {e}") 
        
        return
```

Comment: Подробнее какую ошибку?

Comment: Ошибка загрузки изображения: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f9461876020>

Comment: Добавьте после `response = requests.get(photo_url)` вот эту строку `print(response.status_code)` и напишите что оно вывело.

Comment: 404 
Ошибка загрузки изображения: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f9467ce07c0>

Comment: 404 - значит что картинка по-данному url не найдена. Вы используете тот-же url что и в вопросе?

Comment: Вообще, url в вопросе был для примера, если честно. Изначально каждый раз фотографию я пытаюсь подтянуть из телеграм бота. Это выглядит примерно так:

 photo_url = message.photo[-1].file_id 
    photo_info = bot.get_file(photo_url) 
    time.sleep(1) 
    photo_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{6084234069}/{photo_info.file_path}'

Comment: `photo_url = message.photo[-1].file_id
a = io.BytesIO(bot.download_file(bot.get_file(photo_url).file_path))
img = Image.open(a).convert('RGB')`  используйте вот такой код.

Comment: @CindyLongstickluv вы хотите сохранить изображение в формате картинки (png) или просто получить в байтовом формате?

Comment: @AlezProgrammer мне необходимо именно jpg изображение :(

Comment: @gord1402 теперь выдает такую: Ошибка загрузки изображения: Invalid URL 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAMtZFvZQHNGSyawTQaQlztTNO0_JAkAApXMMRtfk9lKiu3axweuxnABAAMCAAN4AAMvBA': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant 
 "http://AgACAgIAAxkBAAMtZFvZQHNGSyawTQaQlztTNO0_JAkAApXMMRtfk9lKiu3axweuxnABAAMCAAN4AAMvBA?"

Comment: @CindyLongstickluv https://pastebin.com/896hwjJf проверь вот этот код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый короткий и верный способ - просто конвертировать.

```python
import io
import requests 
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError
from PIL import ImageFile 

photo_url = f'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_92x30dp.png'  
try: 
    # Скачиваем фотографию 
    ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True 
    response = requests.get(photo_url) 
    a = io.BytesIO(response.content) 
    img = Image.open(a)

    img.save('img.png') # сохраняем в формате png
    
    rgb_im = img.convert('RGB') # конвертируем
    rgb_im.save('colors.jpg') # сохраняем результат в формате jpg

except (UnidentifiedImageError, OSError) as e: 
    print(f"Ошибка загрузки изображения: {e}")
```